# Is module information retained at runtime?

Tags: java, module

I have the following 2 questions:

Is JPMS module information retained at runtime? 
If so how is it provided?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: What do you mean by "module"? Maven modules? Gradle subprojects? JPMS modules? IntelliJ modules? OSGi bundles? Something else?

Comment: Sorry for that! I meant JPMS modules. Thank and apologies for the lack of information.

Comment: Yes, JPMS modules are retained at runtime. The `module-info.java` file is compiled into a `module-info.class` file and the module descriptor is read, and its access rules enforced, at runtime _if using the module-path_. The [`java.lang.module`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/package-summary.html) package provides documentation, along with the classes `java.lang.Module` and `java.lang.ModuleLayer`. There's also [§7.7 of the _Java Language Specification_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7).

Comment: Other than that, you may want to clarify what sort of answer you want for "how is it provided?". What specific information are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it actually answers my question. Also sorry for the way I structured it, but it was my first question on stackoverflow.